# "Error at startup: Error creating directory, hr=5" when running AirSim

Tags: unreal-engine4, airsim

When I download Unreal Environment and clone AirSim trying to run it, I met this box:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OSyFa.png)
Before this, I have successfully built AirSim(with --no-fully-pole-car). I did not clone AirSim to default address in C drive but to E drive because C drive do not have enough capacity. It seems to be because the access is denied, a folder does not have permission to modify.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T3Lzz.png)
But nothing happen after I add permissions to folder AirSim and Epic Game. Still the same error.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rk6x4.png)
Anyone know the reason, or have met the same error?

Expect someone can solve my problem.